# Logback using Springboot not accepting environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-logback

I am trying to use an environment variable ($mode) in my logbook-spring.xml as below but logback is unable to read it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="../logs/${mode}"/>
    <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/archive"/>
    <timestamp key="timestamp-by-second" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>
    <timestamp key="timestamp-by-day" datePattern="yyyyMMdd"/>
    <appender name="Trace-Appender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/emrTrace_${mode}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/emrTrace_${mode}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %msg%n</pattern>
            <outputPatternAsHeader>true</outputPatternAsHeader>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.itreatmd.emr.Debug" level="finest" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Trace-Appender"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

I run my executable jar as:

java -jar EmrServices-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --mode=prod

The property "LOG_PATH" is being set to "logs/mode_IS_UNDEFINED"

As such, when I iterate through my environment variables in the program, I do see "mode" among the variables. Which means that the application is aware of the variable. But apparently, logback is not.

I am using Spring 2.1.10. I didn't see this problem in much older versions of Springboot (1.3)

Edit: I am thinking that the reason for this is that logback is initialized before Spring, but I have no idea on what I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following property to the configuration of your logback.xml

```
<property resource="application.properties" />
```

Or Alternatively

```
<springProperty name="mode" source="mode"/>
```

Comment: No, made no difference. I am not sure why it would have as I am passing the environment params on command line (--mode=prod)